# PL/SQL oracle function with ora-01744 INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have set of  functions in myqsl that I need to write oracle versions.

Which is going well until I face **limit 1** issue. I think my query for limit is the problem but couldn't figure out what's wrong. Can you give me a hand?

*MySQL version*

```
SELECT concat(fld_name, ' ', fld_surname) 
   INTO info 
FROM tbl_customer 
WHERE fld_flat_id = flatId and fld_type = typeId 
order by fld_own_date desc limit 1;
```

*Oracle version* (causing the problem)

```
SELECT Q1.* 
FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS RWNR2, Q2.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT (NAME || ' ' || SURNAME) 
           INTO info 
        FROM TB_CUSTOMER 
        WHERE FLAT_ID = flatId AND TYPE = typeId 
        ORDER BY OWN_DATE DESC
    ) Q2 
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1 
 ) Q1 
 WHERE Q1.RWNR2 >  0;
```

And by the way I know table names and fields are different, values are correct in this preview.

Comment: yea I editted that part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `INTO` clause must be in the outer-most `SELECT` not the inner one. And you don't need two levels of nesting, one derived table and a `rownum <= 1` is enough.

So it should be something like this:

```
SELECT full_name
  INTO info
FROM (
    SELECT (NAME || ' ' || SURNAME) as full_name
    FROM TB_CUSTOMER 
    WHERE FLAT_ID = flatId 
      AND TYPE = typeId 
    ORDER BY OWN_DATE DESC
) Q2 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
```

Note that it might still fail with a "no rows found" error if the inner select does not return anything.

Comment: Allright, that seems to work. I understand the point. But is there anything I can do for "no rows found" error?

Comment: @FreshPro: you need to properly catch the "no_data_found" exception in your code and handle it. Or create a SQL statement that always returns something.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip. I will just return an empty string for info. Cheers